# Error while connecting node to mongodb using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i'm getting this error while connecting node to mongodb:

```
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:27017
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  | }]
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
techworld-js-docker-demo-app-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Docker-compose.yaml file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-app:
    image: nihalchandra/myapp:4.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always # fixes MongoNetworkError when mongodb is not ready when mongo-express starts
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
   driver: local
```

done this in server.js file:

```
let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";
```

i tried changing the server but it still didnt work

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is about the Mongo Express connection, right? So the bit about server.js is irrelevant as that is in your app.

Comment: I believe this is normal behaviour. Express can't connect at first because Mongo isn't ready. Your `restart: always` makes Express start again until Mongo *is* ready. Or does Express keep failing?

Answer (score -1):

You should add into your my-app definition a link to database:

```
my-app:
  image: nihalchandra/myapp:4.0
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  links:
    - mongodb:mongodb
```

Then your application will be able to connect to MongoDB using `mongodb` as a hostname.

More details about this you can find in documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/